# How to exclude META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA' in sbt

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

I  have created jar from Intellij for spark+ scala code and try to run the jar in the dev cluster, But I  end up with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:286)
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:239)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:317)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:228)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:348)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:415)
        at sun.misc.JarIndex.getJarIndex(JarIndex.java:137)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:674)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:666)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(URLClassPath.java:665)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:638)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:366)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:356)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:355)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:332)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:198)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:174)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:689)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
    enter code here
```

Could you please advise how to  exclude META-INF details?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add a `maven-shade` plugin and use the `excludes` like follows:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
           ..
          <filters>
            <filter>
              <artifact>*:*</artifact>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </filter>
          </filters>
```

This will remove the signed files and address your issue.